# "Tab" button delete code not move in Xcode

Tags: xcode

There any solution to solve this problem: sometimes I need change indent in code and in some another IDE you can select code and press "Tab" button. But in Xcode this key delete the code and move by indent. How I can change indent in some selected block of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indentation you can make with combination of `Command` and `[` (to the left) and `]` (to the right) buttons respectively.